# how to write the query the below table

Tags: mysql

My table name emp :

table data having the below :

```
   id    name dep_id salary
    1      x     10    2000
    2      y     20    3000
    3      z     30    1000
    4      c     40    500
    5      xc    50    100
    6      b     60    10
    7      l     70    4000
    8      m     80    5000
    9      n     90    10000
    10     dd    100   100
    11      gg    20    4000
    12      vv    10    2000
```

my requirement is show the each department highest two salary employee details.

Comment: plz do some research before post here!

Comment: this will help u: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/115250/Department-wise-top-2-highest-salary-where-departm

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, but I expect if this is for a test they won't believe you wrote it:-

```
SELECT id, name, dep_id, salary
FROM
(
    SELECT id, name, dep_id, salary, @DepCnt := IF(@Dep=dep_id, @DepCnt + 1, 1) AS DepartmentCounter, @Dep:=dep_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, name, dep_id, salary
        FROM emp
        ORDER BY dep_id, salary DESC
    ) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @DepCnt:=1, @Dep:=0) Sub1
) Sub2
WHERE DepartmentCounter <= 2
```

Inner select gets all the rows in deparatment order, then descending salary within that.

Then the next outer select adds a counter to each row, starting at 1 for the row with highest salary per department.

Then the outer select just gets those where the counter is 1 or 2.

SQLfiddle example of it:-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3643e/1

EDIT - Expanded to bring back the details if more than 1 person has the same salary which is one of the top 2 salaries:-

```
SELECT id, name, dep_id, salary
FROM
(
    SELECT id, name, dep_id, salary, @DepCnt := IF(@Dep=dep_id, IF(@PrevSalary=salary, @DepCnt, @DepCnt + 1), 1) AS DepartmentCounter, @Dep:=dep_id, @PrevSalary:=salary
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, name, dep_id, salary
        FROM emp
        ORDER BY dep_id, salary DESC
    ) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @DepCnt:=1, @Dep:=0, @PrevSalary:=0) Sub1
) Sub2
WHERE DepartmentCounter <= 2
```

Comment: @Kickstart what if in a single **`department` 3 employees** with same **`salary 500`**

Comment: @Luv - it will bring back 2 of the 3. It would be easy to expand to cope with bringing back the 3 employees if required.

Answer (score 0):

**Query**:

```
select e.* 
from emp e
inner join (
              SELECT 
              dep_id,
              salary,
              ( 
                CASE dep_id 
                WHEN @curType 
                THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
                ELSE @curRow := 1
                AND @curType := dep_id END
                )AS sequence_No
                FROM emp, 
                (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
                ORDER BY  dep_id,salary desc 
)t on t.dep_id=e.dep_id and t.salary=e.salary
where t.sequence_No<=2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0229/8/0)**:

```
| ID | NAME | DEP_ID | SALARY |
|----|------|--------|--------|
| 13 |   xx |     10 |   5000 |
|  1 |    x |     10 |   2000 |
| 12 |   vv |     10 |   2000 |
| 11 |   gg |     20 |   4000 |
|  2 |    y |     20 |   3000 |
|  3 |    z |     30 |   1000 |
|  4 |    c |     40 |    500 |
|  5 |   xc |     50 |    100 |
|  6 |    b |     60 |     10 |
|  7 |    l |     70 |   4000 |
|  8 |    m |     80 |   5000 |
|  9 |    n |     90 |  10000 |
| 10 |   dd |    100 |    100 |
```